# Size of div depending on size of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a div which contains 2 other divs. They are vertically aligned. Now, the lower div is changing its size via javascript. What I want now is that the upper div is changing its size depending on the other divs size. Is there a way to do this with css style only, without using js?

UPDATE: The outer div has a fixed size.

```
<div>
 <div> childdiv 1</div>
 <div> childdiv 2</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Ok I didnt make this clear enough, the lower box is changing its height in top direction. And the upper div should then decrease its height.

Comment: Can you add your HTML/CSS? A [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) would also be useful.

Comment: can you put some code for us to see?

Comment: Well I simplified my problem to ask this question. In real its all divided in seperate classes. So It's hard to post here. But is there no general answer to this problem?

Comment: You perhaps want something like an accordion menu where both div fills there container and when the size of one is changed the other should adapt its height to again fill the container?

Comment: It's impossible to say if there's a general answer, because you haven't described your problem in enough detail.

Comment: The problem is not clear. So all I can say is, use jquery to call a javascript function whenever your bottom div changes width and then set the width property of the upper div by reading the value of the bottom div width using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display:table` and `display:table-row` to change the height of the upper div accordingly, so that the total height matches the fixed height of the container:

```
#outer{
   display:table;
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
}

#inner1{
    background-color:red;
    display:table-row;
}

#inner2{
    background-color:green;
    display:table-row;
    height:30px;
}
```

You'll find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bRg6m/

Is this what you want?

Added: Note that this doesn't work in IE7 or older. You'll have to use a Javascript solution if you want to support those browsers.

Comment: this looks promising, I will try this this evening.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question.
I made an example here where the upper div is changing its width depending on the lower divs size. Is that what you needed?

http://jsfiddle.net/8fwXR/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    float: left;
}

#box1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#box2 {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: In your example, box1 should decrease its size by the amount box2 increases its size.

Comment: When you talk about size, are you talking about both height and width?

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your setup. The easiest way by far would be to just apply the javascript code to both DIVs at the same time.

Setting the width of the first DIV to be `100%` should cause it to resize the width to match the second DIV (as the resize will force the parent DIV to increase in width too), but you will have a problem when trying to get the height to match, as with pure CSS the first DIV will have no reference to recalculate its own height to match.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kc5BV/)

Alternatively, instead of making the second DIV resize you could resize the parent DIV and have both children set with CSS as follows:

```
width:100%;
height:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is what I meant:

```
document.getElementById("upperDiv").style.width = document.getElementById("bottomDiv").style.width
```